# Fetching Canvas based graph in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I want to fetch HTML of [this graph](http://middlecoin2.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reports/1AV24hjDkkSSFdcioPEB9ooUPMLi64GMi.html) but I don't see how to do it? Is there anyway to fetch it or do I need to use iFrame to load this page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the page, and have the chrome extension loaded, you can use a content script like so:

Background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},function(tabs){
    var tab = tabs[0];
    if(tab.url === "your url"){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"contentscript.js"});
    }
 });
```

contentscript.js

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  var graph =  document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  //do stuff
});
```

You can either do stuff with graph in the content script, or pass it back to the background page with [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging-host)

Comment: I mean to fetch html of remote page. I have put the link too